# How to draw line between the markers in google map, using laravel5.2

Tags: php, google-maps, laravel-5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyByrgAtWpei65izUKYhdyr9-r54rrMZ8Zc&callback=initialize">
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('ico/opengts.png') }}">
    <title>Open GTS</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="themes/assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/carousel.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- NAVBAR
    ================================================== -->

    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand active" href="#">Geo Punch Solution</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class=""><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="{{ url('aboutUs') }}">About Us</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="{{ url('accountAdmin') }}">Account Admin</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('userAdmin') }}">User Admin </a></li>

                            <li><a href="{{ url('vehicleAdmin') }}">Vehicle Admin </a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('groupAdmin') }}">Group Admin </a></li>

                            <li><a href="{{ url('geozoneAdmin') }}">Geozone Admin </a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('changePassword') }}">Change Password </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<script>
function initialize() {
var map = document.getElementById('map');
// Put all locations into array
                    var locations = [
                        @foreach ($location as $locations)
                        [ {{ $locations->latitude }}, {{ $locations->longitude }} ],
@endforeach
];
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                     if(i==0)
                                {
                                    // Initialise the map
                                    var map_options = {
                                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][0], locations[0][1]),
                                        //position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
                                        zoom: 10,
                                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                    }

                                    var maps = new google.maps.Map(map, map_options);
                                }



                      //  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
                            //center:location,
                            map: maps,
                            icon:'jeep.png'
                            //animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
                        });
}

                    var locationPath = new google.maps.Polyline
                    ({
                        path:new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
                        geodesic: true,
                        strokeColor: '#FFCCFF',
                        strokeOpacity: 2.0,
                        strokeWeight:2,
                        map:maps

                    });
                   locationPath.setMap(map);
 }

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
                    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                            'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                            'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
                }
              </script>

            <style type="text/css">
                #map {
                    width: 1170px;
                    height: 570px;
                    margin-top: 100px;
                    margin-left: 100px;
                }
            </style>
        </div>
    </div>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>
<p id="error"></p>
</body>
{{--<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->--}}
{{--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>--}}
{{--<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>--}}
{{--<script src="{{ asset('js/holder.js') }}"></script>--}}

{{--</body>--}}
</html>
```

This is my map page. Using this code, I am able to fetch `latLng` and it's displaying on the Map.

But, I am not able draw line between the markers.

Can anyone help me to find out the mistake that I made in my code? I am using Google Map and the framework is Laravel 5.2.

All the markers are pointing perfectly. Only the problem is with the `Polyline` method. Where should I write that code in my program or in Laravel or do we need to use any other method for drawing the line? I am new in Laravel. So, I need your help to come out from this. Any replies will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume you can display marker on map, you can use following code to draw line between markers.

```
// Put these with your "Initialise the map" section

// init the polyline and set map
var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#FFCCFF',
    strokeOpacity: 2.0,
    strokeWeight:2,
    map:maps
  });
// Get the path form polyLine
var path = poly.getPath();
```

Run at each for loop(same as your maker)

```
// Push the location into PolyLine's path
path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]))
```

For your code:

JSbin: http://jsbin.com/kivukisamu/edit?html,js,output

```
function initialize() {
    var map;
    var poly;
    var path;

    // Put all locations into array
    var locations = [
        [0, 1],
        [30, 20]
    ];
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        if(i==0)
        {
            // Initialise the map
            var map_options = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][0], locations[0][1]),
                //position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), map_options);
            poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
                strokeColor: '#FFCCFF',
                strokeOpacity: 2.0,
                strokeWeight:10,
                map:map
            });
            path = poly.getPath();
        }

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
            //center:location,
            map: map,
            icon:'jeep.png'
            //animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        });

        path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]));
    }

}
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-complex

Comment: : so i need to write all code inside the "Initialize the map"?. when i give path inside Polyline. like            path:path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1])),    am getting error  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". Can you please explain?

Comment: If your marker and line won't change. you can put all the code inside your `initialize` function. I mean that you can put "init the polyline" and "get path from polyline" in your `if(i==0)`

Comment: i did like that only. but it's saying that "cannot read the property 'push' of undefined". How we write path.push in Polyline?

Comment: I add code to jsbin, it work. I move some var declaration, maybe you can look if there is something wrong

Comment: (Y) However, i suggest you move code inside `if(i==0)` before for loop, your code will be cleaner :)

Comment: yeah, i did like that only

Answer (score 0):

The path property of the PolyLine object expects an array or array literals of lat / lng.
Example:

```
path: {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214}
```

so replace your current code:

```
path:new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
```

with coordinates for the two markers you wish to connect with a PolyLine:

```
path: [{lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
       {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821}]
```

Comment: Actually it's my live project. Am talking LatLng value from the remote database, So can't give static value. am getting LatLng in the form of array only. Like below   var locations = [
                                                [ 13.00332, 77.59756 ],
                                                [ 13.00332, 77.59756 ],
                                                [ 13.00332, 77.59756 ], ];